# Matplotlib : How to produce the below chart containing all x-axis labels and gridlines accordingly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
data = {'tenor': ['1w','1m','3m','6m','12m','1y','2y','3y','4y','5y','6y','7y','10y','15y','20y','25y','30y','40y','50y'],'rate_s': [0.02514, 0.026285, 0.0273, 0.0279, 0.029616, 0.026526, 0.026028, 0.024, 0.025958,0.0261375, 0.026355, 0.026, 0.026898, 0.0271745, 0.02741, 0.027, 0.0275, 0.0289,0.0284],'rate_t':[ 0.02314, 0.024285, 0.0253,0.0279, 0.028616, 0.026526,0.027028, 0.024, 0.025958,0.0271375, 0.02355, 0.026, 0.024898, 0.0271745, 0.02641,0.027, 0.0255, 0.0289,0.0284]}
```

I want to produce the chart with the same format like below. I tried this piece of code but results are not satisfactory. It also not showing all x-axis labels. Please suggest.

```
ax = plt.gca()

df.plot(kind='line',x='tenor',y='rate_s',marker='o',color='green',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='tenor',y='rate_y',marker='o', color='red', ax=ax)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(which='major',linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='blue')
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit: `df=pd.DataFrame(...` produces errors.

Comment: My apologies. I rectified the dataframe. Please see now.

Comment: Why did you ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855156/matplotlib-how-to-populate-the-below-chart-having-all-the-x-axis-labels-and-gr) again? Please don't do this. Instead, add more information to the original question.

Comment: What does `'1m'` represent?

Comment: Is [this new question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855156/matplotlib-how-to-populate-the-below-chart-having-all-the-x-axis-labels-and-gr) not practically identical to this one? In any case, please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib : How to populate the below chart having all the x-axis labels and grid lines accordingly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855156/matplotlib-how-to-populate-the-below-chart-having-all-the-x-axis-labels-and-gr)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the time periods into `timedelta` and plot:

```
df['periods'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.tenor).dt.total_seconds()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
df.plot(x='periods',y=['rate_s','rate_t'], ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks(df.periods);
ax.set_xticklabels(df.tenor)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]